# How to throw exception in main thread when CompletableFuture finished exceptionally immediately

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

When my service is called, I have 2 `@Async` FeignClient APIs getBookAsync, getAuthorAsync to check things:

```java
@Async
public CompletableFuture<JsonNode> getBookAsync(Long id) {
    CompletableFuture<JsonNode> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    try {
        future.complete(bookClient.getBook(id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        future.completeExceptionally(e);
    }
    return future; }
```

`getAuthorAsync` is the same as above.

Then if both of the checks is correct, I will save the record it:

```java
CompletableFuture.allOf(bookFuture, authorFuture)
    .thenRun(() -> recordRepository.save(record));
```

I want to throw the error that `bookClient.getBook(id)` thrown **immediately** in the **main thread** if there's one because there's no reason to check author if book already failed.

The error will be handle by a global exception handler.

Comment: The method name says it's async, but it's not. The call to `bookClient.getBook(id)` is done synchronously, and its result is set as the value of the future. When this method ends, the future is always completed - either successfully or exceptionally.

Comment: Note that you should checkout structured concurrency (preview feature in Java 21). It allows you to create seemingly unrelated futures, but cancel other still running futures if one of them fails. You won't be able to use that right now, but it's worth considering when it becomes stable.